# Проблема с const при перегрузке оператора

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Вот кусок кода:

```
const String operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2) const;
}; //здесь кончается описание класса
const String String::operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2)const{}
```

На него выдаётся такая ошибка:

```
error: ‘const String String::operator+(const String&, const String&) const’ must take either zero or one argument
```

Мол оператор, член класса, может принимать только один аргумент. Убираем `String::`

```
const String operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2) const;
};
const String operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2)const{}
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
error: non-member function ‘const String operator+(const String&, const String&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
```

Так как быть? И чтоб принимал два аргумента и чтоб константным был?
Приём двух аргументов - чтобы можно было писать s = 'a' + s; т.е. когда определён конструктор от  char и он стоит левым аргументом (оператор, принимающий один аргумент, может левым аргументом принимать только объект класса, а там у нас char - не работает, в общем, надо два аргумента)
Константность, думаю, понятно для чего.

При всём при этом компилируется без проблем класс `Matrix`, где вроде всё так же написано, как и в классе `String`, который не компилится:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    double data[5][5];
public:
    Matrix()
    {
        // Присваиваем всем элементам массива значение 0.0
        for (int row=0; row < 5; ++row)
            for (int col=0; col < 5; ++col)
                data[row][col] = 0.0;
    }

    double& operator()(int row, int col);
    const double& operator()(int row, int col) const; // для константных объектов
};

double& Matrix::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    //assert(col >= 0 && col < 5);
    //assert(row >= 0 && row < 5);

    return data[row][col];
}

const double& Matrix::operator()(int row, int col) const
{
    //assert(col >= 0 && col < 5);
    //assert(row >= 0 && row < 5);

    return data[row][col];
}
```

Вот мой класс полностью:

```
class String{
private:
  char* str;
  int size;

public:
  static int COUNT;
  static int DEF_LEN;
  String(const char* text, const int size): size(size) {
    ++COUNT;
    str = new char[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      str[i] = text[i];
    }
  }

  String(const char ch){

  }

  ~String(){
    delete[] str;
    --COUNT;
  }

  String(const String& s): size(s.size) {
    ++COUNT;
    str = new char[size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      str[i] = s.str[i];
    }
  }

  static int const get_cnt() {return COUNT;}
  int const get_size() {return size;}

  void const print(){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      cout << str[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
  }

  String& operator =(const String& s){
    if (this == &s) {return *this;}
    else{
      delete[] str;
      size = s.size;
      str = new char[size];
      for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        str[i] = s.str[i];
      }
    return *this;
    }
  }

  String& operator +=(const String& s){
    char* tmp = new char[size + s.size];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
      tmp[i] = str[i];
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size; ++i) {
      tmp[size + i] = s.str[i];
    }
    delete[] str;
    size += s.size;
    str = tmp;
  }

  const String operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2) const;

};

int String::COUNT = 0;
int String::DEF_LEN = 250;

const String String::operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2)const{
  String s = s1;
  s+=s2;
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Зачем вы хотите, чтобы свободная функция была "константной"? Вы понимаете, что делает `const` справа от функции? Для функций-членов он изменяет тип `this` (который неявно передается в функцию) на 'указатель на константу'. В свободные функции `this` неявно не передается, поэтому `const` не имеет смысла.

Comment: Кажется, ты `static` забыл.

Comment: А первый вариант у вас не компилируется потому, что параметр должен быть один. В него передается правый операнд. А левый операнд - это `this`. Еще, `const String` из функций лучше не возвращать. Это заставляет компилятор использовать копирование вместо перемещения, так что может вредить производительности (хотя здесь это ни на что не влияет, потому что вы не написали перемещающий конструктор и оператор присваивания). Если вы ставите `const`, чтобы запись вроде `a+b=c` не компилировалась, то этого можно добиться, переписав оператор присваивания так: `String& operator=(const String& s) & {...}`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Хорошо. тогда и не буду использовать const справа.

Comment: @ריקריצ'ארדוביצ' Если перегружаете внутри класса (первый вариант), то `const` справа стоит ставить. Если снаружи класса - то нельзя.

Comment: @ריקריצ'ארדוביצ' Под `{...}` я имел в виду тело функции. А `&` не дает вызывать эту функцию на временных объектах (rvalue). https://habr.com/ru/post/216783/

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Т.е. & амперсандом фиксится то, что компилятор позволяет делать присваивание для rvalue над не встроенными типами?
Хм, интересно, спасибо

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Извиняюсь, а тут ошибка вылазит
```string.cpp:84:53: error: non-member function ‘String operator+(const String&, const String&)’ cannot have ref-qualifier
 String operator +(const String& s1,const String& s2)&{
```

Comment: Ну дык для `+` это не нужно. Вызывать `+` на временных объектах - нормально. Это нужно только для `=`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ахах, да, не туда написал, извините